# Debug Weblogic application deployed with maven-weblogic-plugin

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, remote-debugging, jdeveloper

I have a web application running on Weblogic server that I have to modify.
For this purpose I've installed JDeveloper 11g R2 with Integrated Weblogic 10.3 server.

Application came as maven project - I've imported maven project into JDeveloper. But although I can compile, attempts to deploy from within JDeveloper fail (server will complain to missing 3rd party classes).

With maven however I can successfully build a war package and deploy it to Integrated Weblogic server (`maven-weblogic-plugin:deploy`).

The question is how do I debug my application?

I tried remote debugging as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html) and after passing proper options to server I can attach to it with JPDA debugger, but it won't stop on breakpoints...

Am I doing something wrong or will only work with webapp deployed directly from JDeveloper?

Comment: If execution is not stopping at the breakpoints? this means that debugging itself is not happening right? you have anything else to prove that debug settings are correct and debugging is happening?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct.  You need to enable remote debugging on Weblogic by modifying the startWeblogic.cmd file.  Verify your settings are correct again.

I typically use the following:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n %SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS%
```

Here is also some documentation I used when setting it up originally:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm

Comment: I had following options:
`set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n`
and as I've written - I am able to connect to WebLogic from JDeveloper, but execution of code does not stop on breakpoints I set.